# /etc/profile[278]: ulimit: 1048576: limit exceeded [Operation not permitted]

Tags: linux, redhat, shell, ulimit

```
[root@bteir airwide]# su - ins
Last login: Wed Aug 12 22:31:40 CDT 2020 on pts/0
/etc/profile[278]: ulimit: 1048576: limit exceeded [Operation not permitted]
ins ins>
```

This log is kept on writing whenever I switch users.

Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You gave the answer in your question: you have a ulimit statement inside your `/etc/profile` which requires root permissions. Since this file is parsed at every login, every non-root user will see that error. Move these settings to a startup script or to `/etc/sysctl.conf`, if you want these settings to be active system-wide, and you're good...